# Security of the trivium stream cipher

Tags: random-number-generator, pseudo-random-generator, stream-cipher, key-generation

So I've been trying to implement a Non-Deterministic RBG based on randomness polling from non-hardware sources (nothing novel, just a side-project). Since collecting entropy and further conditioning is a fairly expensive process, I am using these bits to seed a CSPRNG which finally provides the user with a stream of random bits at a very fast rate.

I've looked into a few designs for this purpose, and Trivium (part of the eSTREAM portfolio) seems to be a good candidate. As for what I can find, there haven't been any significantly more effective attacks on Trivium since it was first adopted. Are there any such weaknesses I am unaware of? Even though the cipher guarantees 2^64 keystream bits, I will reseed the internal state with a new key-iv pair after a certain amount of bits are generated. I haven't decided on a number yet, but that's kind of the plan. Can anyone guide me on if this is a good model?

Comment: It is of course possible to perform a full re-key, but I'd mix the new entropy into the state somehow instead. The problem is that if your entropy sources have a problem that you might not get true random values if you *just* rely on their state at a certain instant of time. Furthermore, unless you need a lightweight PRNG, you might be better off using a NIST defined one which does take explicit care of reseeding.